# Software for the atom model of all elements

Tags: electronic-configuration, software, atomic-structure

I want an atom model with shells but I haven't found one yet and the only software that created an atom was Cinema 4D. This software is not for beginners like me and I used a tutorial to make an atom but it was really hard until I knew how to create shells, electrons, protons and neutrons.

Does anyone know a replacement for Cinema 4D? I checked the list in Google and I found molecules which is not what I wanted to find.

[image]

Comment: Something like this in that picture or something in 2d if it's not possible in 3d?

Answer (score 3):

For $\mathrm{\LaTeX}$ users there is [`bohr`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bohr) package by [Cle­mens Nieder­berger](https://ctan.org/author/niederberger) which

> provides means for the creation of simple Bohr models of atoms up to the atomic number 112.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
    \chemsetup{modules = all}
\usepackage{bohr}
    \setbohr{
        shell-options-add = dashed,
        shell-dist = .5em,
        insert-missing,
        atom-style={\footnotesize\sffamily\ch}
    }

\begin{document}

\bohr{}{He}
\bohr{10}{O^2-}
\bohr{18}{Ca^2+}
\bohr{30}{As^3+}

\setbohr{
    distribution-method = quantum,
    shell-options-add = {solid,red!25!},
    electron-options-set = {red!75!},
    nucleus-radius = 1.5em
}
\bohr{55}{Ce^3+}
\setbohr{
    distribution-method=periodic,
    shell-options-add = {solid,green!25!},
    electron-options-set = {green!75!},
}
\bohr{55}{Ce^3+}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok but how do I use it?I tried to write in the Latex software and it showed me an error.

Comment: Do I install the package or something like that?

Comment: That's not very informative. What "Latex software" and what error? Are you sure you have necessary packages installed since they are not a part of "minimal" installation of neither TeXLive nor MiKTeX?

Comment: File `libertinehologopatch.sty' not found. }{}

Comment: I downloaded the package from the internet.Is that how the steps work?

Comment: Well, you are missing either one of or both packages since `libertinehologopatch.sty` is written by the same author. I suggest to use your package manager to fetch the packages from the nearby mirror (you still haven't mentioned what LaTeX distro you are using). As for the future, I would recommend to make a *full install* with all the packages. It's going to take up to 5 GB or so with all the docs, examples and so on, but IMO it is worth it.

Comment: I'm using TeXstudio and  MiKTex 2.9.Do I have to install the package in both of these programms?

Comment: No, TeXstudio is an IDE, you don't install packages there. You need to open [MiKTeX Console](https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-console) and make sure both `chemmacros` and `bohr` packages are installed via **package manager**.

Comment: Ok now I have both packages.Is there a tutorial to use bohr?(I don't know how to write the code and I want to learn from somewhere)

Comment: Yes, there is: [bohr's manual](http://ctan.altspu.ru/macros/latex/contrib/bohr/bohr_en.pdf).